# ¿Cómo usar Smart Pointers (shared_ptr) con clases y clases derivadas en C++?

Tags: c++, punteros, clase, clase-anidada, puntero-a-miembro

Estoy intentando crear un programa con una clase base llamada "Vehicle" y dos clases derivadas: "Car" y "Lorry", usando punteros inteligentes.

- La clase "Vehicle" tiene como miembros comunes -> plate, year.
- La clase "Car" le añade el objeto -> horsepower.
- La clse "Lorry" le añade el objeto -> maximum load.

Quiero crear un vector llamado `myGarage` que sea `shared_ptr` con el fin de ir almacenando ahí los coches y los camiones según se vayan añadiendo en la "*Opción 1*" del Menú en el `while`. Pero a la hora de hacer el push_back y el constructor de las clases derivadas ando algo perdida.

Si compilo el error que me sale en la línea de código del `push_back` es:

> error C2664: 'void std::vector,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)':
>
> el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'std::shared_ptr<_Other> (__cdecl *)(_Types &&...)' a 'const _Ty &' 1> with 1> [ 1> _Ty=std::shared_ptr 1> ]

Creo que es problema de como estoy creando mis objetos dentro de mi vector. Tengo mal el constructor de las clases? O es un mal uso de `shared_ptr`?  Cómo puedo solucionar mi error?

No se bien como puedo crear dentro de mi vector `myGarage` los objetos nuevos de las clases derivadas.

Este es el codigo de `main`:

```
  #include "pch.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Vehicle.h"
  using std::cout;
  using std::cin;
  using std::endl;
  #include <vector>
  using std::vector;
  using std::shared_ptr;
  using std::make_shared;
  int PrintMenu();

 int main()
 {
 std::cout << "VEHICLE MANAGEMENT" << endl;

vector<shared_ptr<Vehicle>> myGarage;
while (1) {
    int opMenu = PrintMenu();
    if (opMenu == 5) {
        cout << "\n Error. Not valid action. Try again." << endl;
    }
    else if (opMenu == 4) {
        cout << "\n Good bye." << endl;
        break;
    }
    else if (opMenu == 1) {
        char opClass = 'a';
        cout << "\n\t Vehicle type is Car(c) or Lorry(l)?:  ";
        cin >> opClass;
        if (opClass == 'c' || opClass == 'C') {
            myGarage.push_back(make_shared <Car>);              //I ask data inside the constructor
        }
        else if (opClass == 'l' || opClass == 'L') {
            myGarage.push_back(make_shared <Lorry>);                //I ask data inside the constructor
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n\t Not valid operation. Please try again." << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n Error. Not valid action. Try again." << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}


int PrintMenu()
{
int op = 4;
cout << "\n********GARAGE MENU*******" << endl;
cout << "\n 1. Intoduce vehicle. ";
cout << "\n 2. Take out vehicle. ";
cout << "\n 3. Show vehicles register. ";
cout << "\n 4. Exit. ";
cout << "\n Option: ?";
cin >> op;
if (op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4) { op = 5; }
return op;
}
```

Este es el código de `Vehicle.cpp`:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Vehicle.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;


Vehicle::Vehicle(int y = 2000, string p = "AAA1234")
{
    year = y;
    plate = p;
}

void Vehicle::AskData()
{
    cout << "\n Year of the vehicle? : ";
    cin >> year;
    cout << "\n Plate? : ";
    cin >> plate;
}

void Vehicle::Display() 
{
    cout << "\nYear: " << year << " Plate: " << plate ;
}

string Vehicle::GetPlate()
{
    return plate;
}

Vehicle::~Vehicle()
{
    ;
}

/************** CAR **************/

Car::Car()
{
    AskData();
}

void Car::AskData()
{
    Vehicle::AskData();
    cout << "\n Horsepower? : ";
    cin >> hp;
}

void Car::Display()
{
    Vehicle::Display();
    cout << " Horsepower: " << hp;
}

/************** LORRY **************/

Lorry::Lorry()
{
    AskData();
}

void Lorry::AskData()
{
    Vehicle::AskData();
    cout << "\n Maximum Load? : ";
    cin >> lmax;
}

void Lorry::Display()
{
    Vehicle::Display();
    cout << " Maximum load: " << lmax;
}
```

Y para acabar este es el código de `Vehicle.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Vehicle
{
public:

    Vehicle(int y, string p);
    virtual void AskData();
    void Display();
    string GetPlate();
    ~Vehicle();

protected:
    int year;                   //year of manufacture
    string plate;               //licence plate
};

class Car :public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car();
    void AskData();
    void Display();
private:
    int hp;
};

class Lorry :public Vehicle
{
public:
    Lorry();
    void AskData();
    void Display();
private:
    int lmax;
};
```

Comment: No termino de entender qué problema tienes. ¿Por qué andas perdida? ¿Problemas de compilación? ¿El código funciona mal? ¿No sabes cómo recuperar los elementos? ¿¿??

Comment: Me da error el .push_back al crear un nuevo elemento dentro de mi myGarage. No se si tengo mal el constructor de Vehicle, Car y Lorry para poder usar el shared_ptr o si es fallo de como inserto los elementos en myGarage haciendo `myGarage.push_back(make_shared<Lorry>)`.

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da exactamente? esos detalles sin importancia suelen ser importantes

Comment: Me dice esto, pero no entiendo a que se refiere: `error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': el argumento 1 no puede convertirse de 'std::shared_ptr<_Other> (__cdecl *)(_Types &&...)' a 'const _Ty &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>
1>        ]`

Comment: ¡Echaba de menos preguntas con cierto nivel! ¡Sigue así! El problema es que cuando dices "*a la hora de hacer el push_back y el constructor de las clases derivadas ando algo perdida*" no se a qué te refieres. Añade el error a la pregunta, no a los comentarios.

Comment: Como comentario no, por favor, revisa la pregunta y adáptala para que cumpla con lo que te decimos. Si esperas que alguien se tenga que leer los comentarios para poder responderte vas a recibir muy poquita atención

Comment: Preguntada editada, espero que así se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu programa es una secuencia de errores... empecemos

**Destructor virtual**

La primera norma a la hora de trabajar con polimorfismo es que el destructor de la clase base debe ser virtual. ¿Por qué? Básicamente porque si no el programa puede fallar a la hora de liberar la memoria:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void func()
  { }

  ~Base()
  { std::cout << "~Base\n"; }
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void func() override
  { }

  ~Derivada()
  { std::cout << "~Derivada\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Derivada* d = new Derivada;
  Base* b = new Derivada;

  std::cout << "Destructor1:\n";
  delete d;
  std::cout << "\nDestructor2:\n";
  delete b;
}
```

Si ejecutas este programa obtendrás (aparte de algun posible warning avisándote de que hay algo que está mal), la siguiente salida:

```
Destructor1:
~Derivada
~Base

Destructor2:
~Base
```

¿Por qué en el segundo caso no se ha invocado el destructor de `Derivada`? La respuesta es, ya que estamos hablando justamente de ello, porque el destructor de la clase base no es virtual. Si lo declaras virtual verás como la situación mejora sustancialmente.

Adicionalmente, como estás usando `shared_ptr`, se entiende que estás usando, al menos, el estándar C++11. A partir de este estándar también es posible etiquetar constructores y destructores como `default`. Este modificador obliga al compilador a crear la implementación por defecto para la función... con lo que nos ahorramos tener que implementarla:

```
class Vehicle()
{
public:
  ~Vehicle() = default;
};

// Ya no hay que implementarla
//Vehicle::~Vehicle()
//{
//}
```

La versión por defecto no va a saber liberar la memoria reservada por punteros, pero como no estás usando ninguno no hay peligro.

**Constructor por defecto**

El programa no va a funcionar de ninguna manera porque la clase base declara un constructor específico. Al declarar este constructor, el constructor por defecto se deshabilita (salvo que se declare explícitamente y no es tu caso).  El caso es que las clases derivadas no llaman al constructor de la clase base (que como no es el constructor por defecto hay que invocarlo explícitamente):

```
Car::Car()
  : Vehicle(0,"a")
{
    AskData();
}
```

Ahora bien, como en el propio constructor se llama al método `AskData` cuya finalidad es pedirle al usuario que introduzca los datos que permiten inicializar el objeto (que conste que esta es una forma horrible de inicializar objetos), lo que tendría más sentido aquí es sustituir el constructor de `Vehicle` por el constructor por defecto:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle();
    // Vehicle(int y, string p);
};

//Vehicle::Vehicle(int y = 2000, string p = "AAA1234")
Vehicle::Vehicle()
{
}
```

Por cierto, nota que el valor de los parámetros por defecto hay que indicarlo en la declaración de la función, no en la implementación:

```
// OK
class Vehicle
{
public:
   Vehicle(int y = 1, string p = "A");
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(int y, string p)
{
}

// ERROR
class Vehicle
{
public:
   Vehicle(int y, string p);
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(int y = 2000, string p = "AAA1234")
{
}
```

Volviendo al tema de los constructores... dado que no haces nada especial con los mismos, al menos no con el de `Vehicle`, lo más razonable es no declararlo si quiera, ya se encargará el compilador de crearlo implícitamente (conviene dejar que el compilador se encargue de ciertas cosas):

**Funciones virtuales innecesarias**

Por el uso que tiene, no hay ningún motivo que justifique que la función `AskData` deba ser virtual. Solo se invoca en los constructores de las clases derivadas.

Las funciones virtuales tienen una peculiaridad, y es que para ser invocadas el programa tiene que consultar una tabla de funciones virtuales (llamada típicamente *vTable*). Esta tabla es lo último que se construye del objeto, por lo que invocar funciones virtuales en los constructores puede tener efectos indeseados:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "Base::func()\n"; }

  Base()
  { func(); }
};

struct Derivada : Base
{
  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada::func()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Derivada d; // Imprime Base::func()
  d.func();   // Imprime Derivada::func()
  Base* ptr = &d;
  ptr->func(); // Imprime Derivada::func()
}
```

A ti no te falla porque la función la invocas en la clase derivada... pero vamos, que no es una práctica que quieras llevar a entornos reales porque te puedes llegar a desesperar antes de encontrar un error de este tipo.

Así pues, la función no solo no necesita ser virtual sino que además es peligroso... basta con quitarle el `virtual` y listo, funciona. Aunque ya puestos no estaría de más moverla al apartado `protected`, ya que no tiene sentido que sea pública.

**El error que comentas**

El error se está produciendo porque estás usando mal `make_shared`, ya que se trata de una **función**, luego tiene que tener, necesariamente, paréntesis:

```
if (opClass == 'c' || opClass == 'C') {
    myGarage.push_back(make_shared<Car>());              //I ask data inside the constructor
//                                     ^^
}
else if (opClass == 'l' || opClass == 'L') {
    myGarage.push_back(make_shared<Lorry>());                //I ask data inside the constructor
//                                       ^^
}
```

Comment: @MAP perfecto, ahora, por favor, borra estos comentarios, ya no tienen sentido y ensucian el sitio, yo voy a hacer lo mismo. Un saludo

Comment: @MAP es preferible que publiques una nueva pregunta sobre ese tema. Los comentarios son para aclaraciones temporales, no para dejar respuestas. El motivo es que los comentarios no están indizados en el buscador de [es.so] y que son menos visibles... eso y que su función es preguntar/responder pequeñas aclaraciones. Al publicarlo como pregunta nueva podrá ser de utilidad a más gente

Comment: Además, los comentarios borrados no se pueden recuperar, no son como las preguntas, de las cuales queda constancia aun estando borradas